# How do i fix waswas about shirk?

Tags: shirk, waswasa

I keep getting waswas of shirk, and I watched a video about the existence of God coz I saw it on youtube, and I read a lot of things about people losing their faith and even one or 2 things about apostates (NOT because I wanted to be like them. Is this a sin? I told my parents and friends about my problem. Is that a sin?
I dont know how to get rid of this, because it interferes even whilst doing the dhikr meant to keep it away. Might ruqya help?

Comment: Ruqya is matter on which there's a scholarly dispute. I don't even think it has any relation with waswas.

Comment: So do u know what I could do?

Answer (score 1):

### Having doubt by itself is not a sin.

> It was narrated that Abu Hurayrah (may Allah be pleased with him)
> said: “Some of the Companions of the Messenger of Allah (peace and
> blessings of Allah be upon him) came to the Prophet (peace and
> blessings of Allah be upon him) and said to him, ‘We find in ourselves
> thoughts that are too terrible to speak of.’ He said, ‘Are you really
> suffering from that?’ They said, ‘Yes.’ He said, ‘**That is a clear
> sign of faith**.’”

(Muslim) [Islamqa.info](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/12315/suffering-from-waswas-insinuating-whispers-of-the-shaytan-about-the-essence-of-allah)

Rather it's a good thing to seek knowledge to clear your doubts. You can ask us in this website if you have any questions, regarding about your doubts. And make Dua to Allah to protect you from the whispers of shayatin.

> The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said, “Allah
> will forgive my ummah (followers) for any insinuating whispers that
> may cross their minds, so long as they do not act upon it or speak of
> it.” (Agreed upon).

[Islamqa.info](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/12315/suffering-from-waswas-insinuating-whispers-of-the-shaytan-about-the-essence-of-allah)